# Ubuntu Software Center's only review option showing "No Network Connection"

Tags: networking, network-manager

I can download, install program from **ubuntu software center** program. Everything is okay. But there's a tiny problem is that I can't view any user's review on any program. Please see the screen shot. [No network Connection Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy3Iy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Running `watch -n 1 netstat -tp` at the same time as the software center reveals it's loading that stuff from `https://reviews.ubuntu.com`. If you have a look at that in a browser does it reveal something that's wrong with the connection?

Comment: No.  In web browser, the address is ok. It gives me the right thing. Nothing is wrong with it.